# What causes TSaveDialog dialog to be different?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, savefiledialog

Yesterday at work I noticed 2 very strange things: one of them is this one ([Form is hidden behind other forms when ShowModal is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639125/form-is-hidden-behind-other-forms-when-showmodal-is-called)) and second one is:
I have inherited form. Parent form haves no TSaveDialog. Inherited one haves it. When I build the project and I call the code that opens dialog I see:

- big dialog window
- file extensions
- when I close dialog, focus
  goes to main form (not modal one that called it)

When I double click in Object Inspector on OnClose, just 'inherited' appears. I add some comment and I have it like:

```
procedure TInheritedForm.SaveDialog1Close(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inherited;
  // Thats all here. Parent form haves no TSaveDialog!
end;
```

When I build the project and I call the code that opens dialog I see:

- smaller dialog window
- no file extensions
- when I close dialog, focus
  goes to modal form (the one that called it)

Both things I mentioned seems impossible to me. I got some notes about first issue, what about second one? Thank you.

Comment: This seems to be a bug with the CommonControls (started in Delphi XE) just also mentioned [here (german link)](http://www.delphipraxis.net/180093-diverse-fokusprobleme.html#post1257533) AFAIK this bug is not known to QC and should be reported there

Comment: @SirRufo, should that be the answer?

Comment: @Johan At the moment it is just a hint and I have not enough details to provide a good answer (except the link).

Answer (score 1):

there are some bugs:

MDIChild Form loses focus after showmessage Status: Closed
https://web.archive.org/web/20171220121537/http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=104381

TFindDialog.Execute - Application loses focus and is send to back, behind other Application
https://web.archive.org/web/20171220121735/http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=127572

Find dialog can pick an invisble form as its parent. Upon closing, can send the application backwards
Bug 109470

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).