# TTaskBar - Show another form with TaskBarButtons

Tags: delphi, focus, show, delphi-xe6

I use Delphi XE6 :
I create a TaskBarButton in my TaskBar.
This button is linked on an action who make :

```
TForm2.Create(nil).ShowModal;
```

The Form2 is showing without focus.
And sometimes, with a complex form, the new form appears behind the application and i have to click anywhere for see it.

Why I haven't focus on the new form created by my taskbutton ? (if I click on a simple button, my new form have focus).

Code in my MainForm :

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Unit2, System.Actions, Vcl.ActnList,
  System.Win.TaskbarCore, Vcl.Taskbar;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ActionList1: TActionList;
    Action1: TAction;
    Taskbar1: TTaskbar;
    procedure Action1Execute(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Déclarations privées }
  public
    { Déclarations publiques }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Action1Execute(Sender: TObject);
var
   FormTest : TForm2;
begin
   try
      //self.Enabled := False;
      FormTest := TForm2.Create(nil);
      FormTest.ShowModal;
   finally
      FormTest.Free;
      //self.Enabled := True;
   end;
end;

end.
```

TForm2 is just a new form with component.

Comment: Questions typically contain at least one question mark somewhere. Please read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Exactly, I have edited. Thanks

Comment: See [Form is hidden behind other forms when ShowModal is called](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1639125/576719).

Comment: You leaked that form. If you showed a complete program that would help.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, it's possible to set `caFree` in the close event, so a leak is not definite here, but a possibility. Agreed that without code it's difficult to say. At least the single line for creating and calling showmodal looks dubious.

Comment: @LU-RD : Thank's for this link, but when I click on a simple button, it's OK. It's when I use TTaskBar and TTaskButton that I have this problem.

Comment: @yNG Why won't you show us something that we can run to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : I have just edited for add my Unit1.pas. Is there a solution for upload a project on stackoverflow ?

Comment: The most important in that post, I think, It's a fire action with the an item of "TTaskbar".

Comment: Which Delphi version?

Comment: I Use Delphi XE6 (it's a new VCL component Delphi XE6).

Comment: I can't reproduce this with XE6 on Windows 7 64 bit platform.

Comment: Your `Try..Finally` block is wrong. The `Form2.Create` should come before the `Try`. Not that's the problem, merely an observation.

Comment: @Andy_D: Which the compiler would have explained if hints and warnings were enabled (and the poster was actually reading them).