# I cannot add/change the path to libraries in Delphi 11.1

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I cannot add/change the path to libraries in Delphi 11.1
When I click on the button, the window shows for a second and disappears.
I have no way to modify the paths.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem ?

[image]

UPDATE

Problem partially resolved. When I connect the second screen, everything works fine.

Comment: Have you reported this to the vendor?

Comment: You can use this external tool: https://littleearthsolutions.net/products/delphi-library-helper/

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No, I haven't reported it yet

Comment: Another way to do it, is to click within the path itself. This is how it worked prior to 10.3 anyway.

Comment: Are you using any IDE plugins? If yes, remove them to ensure none of these is the cause for the problem. If it works without the plugins, re-enable them one at a time to find out which one is the culprit and report it. If it doesn't work without the plugins you should definitely report it to Embarcadero.

Comment: This appears to be the problem of showing multiple modal windows at same time. Sometimes Windows doesn't keep the correct Z order of sown modal windows especially if those modal windows also have set to Stay On Top. You can actually read more about this issue in [Form is hidden behind other forms when ShowModal is called](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1639125/3636228). I'm guessing someone at Embarcadero didn't follow the rules for working with modal forms correctly.

Comment: As a workaround you can always move your Options window to the side of the screen before clicking on the three doted button. This way the newly created modal form for editing the path won't be hidden by Options window.

Comment: @SilverWarior I have tried to do this several times. The problem is not that one window cover another. That window just disappears. I solved the problem when I connected the monitor to the notebook and I used 2 screens. Now everything works properly. 
Thank you all for your help !

Comment: @Delphi Coder Your software may indeed be exactly what I need EXCEPT that the issue I'm having is installing JCL/JVCL into the Alexandra 11.3 CE. Your software uses the components I'm having issues with. A suggestion, if you are providing the source for a helper application (well done, I thank you for that) only use those components that are available in a standard Delphi install. Do not assume the user will have installed other packages.

Comment: @KevinBlack that's not my software

Comment: @Delphi Coder Apologies for that, you were just trying to be helpful and I appreciate that. My bad, I should have been more diligent in reviewing the author. Again, please accept my apologies.